# How to identify the future distribution of a stochastic variable from its SDE

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, moment-generating-functions

I would like to know some common practice to identify the future distribution of a random variable modelled by an arbitrary SDE.

Would you study it **empirically** (like generating Monte-Carlo distribution and then performing statistical tests to fit it to known distros) or analytically? Examining the generated MC distribution of the model is a known option to me, however, do you know any common methods/approaches to study it **analytically**, too?

E.g., consider the SDE $$dr_t = a(b-r_t)\, dt + \sigma\sqrt{r_t}\, dW_t,$$

where $dW_t$ is a Brownian motion and $a,b, \sigma$ are constants. Then, $r_{t+T}$ is distributed as a Chi-squared distribution. How would you work to end up to such a conclusion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am a little unsure what you are trying to do .. Compare model results with real data?

Comment: Chinny84, thank you for taking time for my post. I rephrased my question, too. I would like to study the future distribution an SDE (I am not looking at market data at this stage). I would like to study a model mathematically apart from its use in actual markets. I see that I have 2 options. 1) doing MC and trying to fit final state to a known distro 2) or preferably to study it analytically. I could try to derive the moments of this SDE, but in case of the above SDE, I do not know how to conclude that is Chi and Gamma and Inverse Gaussian, or else. Can you give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am right your process is a CIR process and is kind of tricky. Generally, to find a distribution of random variable you can solve its SDE, like in Black-Scholes model. From the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model), you can interpret the CIR equation as a sum of squared [Ornstein-Uhlenbeck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) which can be solved (pretty ugly) analytically. The random variable from an OU process will be normally distributed and you know that the sum of squared normal random variable follows a $\chi^{2}$ distribution. Therefore you can guess that $r_{t+T}$ will follow some kind of $\chi^{2}$ distribution.

You can also solve the Fokker-Planck equation of the process. Guess a functional form for the density, typically exponential, and apply Ito derivation. Then take the expectation and you will have an ODE. Solve it and you will get the probability distribution.