# CIR model. Is there a closed-form solution or even a good proxy of analytical solution?

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, finance, stochastic-differential-equations, numerical-calculus

Is there a closed-form (analytical) solution for the Cox-Ingersoll-Ross SDE
\begin{equation}
dr_t=k_r(\theta_r-r_t)dt+\sigma_r\sqrt{r_t}dW_t\tag{1}
\end{equation}
?
Notice that $\{r_t\}$ is our process of interest, $k_r$ and $\theta_r$ are constant parameters and $dW_t$ denotes Wiener increment.
I would need a closed-form solution of $(1)$ (or even a good analytical proxy) so as to compare it with solution of my numerical simulation of $(1)$. I am aiming at determining the order of accuracy of my numerical solution, so I would need an analytical solution (or something like that) of $(1)$ so as to compute the average error of my simulation code, that is $\mathbb{E}\left(r_t^{TRUE}-r_t^{SIMULATED}\right)$.
Any suggestion or good source?

Comment: Little comment : "proxy" should remain in the computer science domain. Use "approximation" in the framework of mathematics.

Comment: Also asked here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57168/cir-model-is-there-a-closed-form-solution-or-even-a-good-proxy-of-analytical-so

Comment: Some information can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1099310)